# How to store two columns side by side in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code each loop returns one column having length 1728. I want to store both columns side by side. But with the following code I get whole data in one column. Can Someone please help to solve this issue?

```
filename="File"
f=open(filename,'a')
for l in range(M):
    for k in range(M*M):
        arr1.append(l)
        f.write("%s \n" % (l))


for o in range(M):
    for p in range(M):
        for q in range(M):
            arr2.append(p)
            f.write("%s \n" % (p))

f.close()
```

Comment: you have two arrays, use something like `for c in range(0,len(arr1))` and then write each elem like `f.write(array1[c] + " " + array2[c])`

Comment: would of course only work if both arrays have same length

Comment: geting this error :TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: dtype of both arrays is int64

Comment: then try converting them to string with `str(array1[c]) + str(array2[c])`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to produce the file and the lists `arr1` and `arr2` do not need to be accessible in the program, you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) on the comprehensions directly to generate the values and write them directly to the file.

```py
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    for a, b in zip([l for l in range(M) for _ in range(M * M) ],
                    [p for _ in range(M) for p in range(M) for _ in range(M)]):
        f.write(f'{a} {b}\n')
```

If it is important for `arr1` and `arr2` to be accessible within the program, then you can still generate them and use zip:

```py
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    arr1 = [l for l in range(M) for _ in range(M * M)]
    arr2 = [p for _ in range(M) for p in range(M) for _ in range(M)]
    
    for a, b in zip(arr1, arr2):
        f.write(f'{a} {b}\n')
```